# Not adding to the map, Staying the same name "t-1"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making it so if a member says ~new, it makes a new ticket for him, but the problem is, the channel name has to go in a unique number, like t-1 then t-2 ect...

But it's sticking with "t-1" only, to be clear, I'm using a command handler.

here is my code:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'new',
  category: 'Ticket',
  description: 'Creates a new ticket.',
  aliases: ['newticket'],
  usage: 'new',
  userperms: [],
  botperms: [],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {

  let ticketCounter = 1;
  const userTickets = new Map()

        if(userTickets.has(message.author.tag)) {
            return message.channel.send('<@' + message.author.id + '> you already have a ticket, please close your existing ticket first before opening a new one!').then(m => m.delete({timeout: 3000}));
        }
        
        message.guild.channels.create(`t-${ticketCounter}`, {
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: message.author.id,
                    allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
                {
                    id: "916785912267034674",
                    allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
                {
                    id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
            ],
            type: 'text',
        }).then(async channel => {
            channel.setParent('916778691672031293');
            userTickets.set(message.author.id, ticketCounter++);
            message.channel.send(`<@` + message.author.id + `>, you have successfully created a ticket! Please click on ${channel} to view your ticket.`).then(m => m.delete({timeout: 3000}));
            channel.send(`Hi <@` + message.author.id + `>, welcome to your ticket! Please be patient, we will be with you shortly.`);
            
            const logchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'test');
            
            if(logchannel) {
                logchannel.send(`Ticket-${ticketCounter} created. Click the following to veiw <#${channel.id}>`);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your logic is a bit confusing to me because you are incrementing in a statement, but are you aware that `foo++` returns the current value of `foo` and then increases, and `++foo` increases the value first and _then_ returns?

Comment: ticketCounter is reset to 1 every time the run method gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`<Map>.size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size) instead of an incrementer since the code is reexecuted after each command, the counter will be set to 1 each time.

```js
if(!client.userTickets) client.userTickets = new Map();
client.userTickets.set(message.author.id, client.userTickets.size + 1);
message.guild.channels.create(`t-${client.userTickets.size + 1}`, { ... });
```

Example for your code:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'new',
  category: 'Ticket',
  description: 'Creates a new ticket.',
  aliases: ['newticket'],
  usage: 'new',
  userperms: [],
  botperms: [],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {

  if(!client.userTickets) client.userTickets = new Map()

        if(client.userTickets.has(message.author.id)) {
            return message.channel.send('<@' + message.author.id + '> you already have a ticket, please close your existing ticket first before opening a new one!').then(m => m.delete({timeout: 3000}));
        }
        
        message.guild.channels.create(`t-${client.userTickets.size + 1}`, {
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: message.author.id,
                    allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
                {
                    id: "916785912267034674",
                    allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
                {
                    id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                },
            ],
            type: 'text',
        }).then(async channel => {
            channel.setParent('916778691672031293');
            client.userTickets.set(message.author.id, client.userTickets.size + 1);
            message.channel.send(`<@` + message.author.id + `>, you have successfully created a ticket! Please click on ${channel} to view your ticket.`).then(m => m.delete({timeout: 3000}));
            channel.send(`Hi <@` + message.author.id + `>, welcome to your ticket! Please be patient, we will be with you shortly.`);
            
            const logchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'test');
            
            if(logchannel) {
                logchannel.send(`Ticket-${client.userTickets.size} created. Click the following to veiw <#${channel.id}>`);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused, where do I put these?

Comment: I edited my answer to fit with your code @Hamoodiyoutube

Comment: (node:244) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined

Comment: Nvm, the same error, but it works in the discord.

Comment: Can you give me the line where the error occurs?

Comment: Sure, here:

    at /home/runner/DwaCraft-Main-bot/commands/ticket/new.js:42:64

Comment: My bad, I puted `client.clientTickets` instead of `client.userTickets`, edited

Comment: It's ok, thanks :D

Comment: I don't know if you did it voluntarily or not, to check if the user already has a ticket you are using tag instead of his id

Comment: When it logs it, it send number 2 when the ticket is 1, I think just remove the `+ 1` right?

Comment: Yes, still my bad

Comment: Oh, I forgot to change it back, I was just having it like that to allow me to make more than one to test :D

Comment: It's ok, you just fixed days of pain xD

Comment: Perfect, all should work now ^^

Comment: It's all working, thanks again :D

Comment: One last thing, how can I make it check if that kind of ticket name already exits, as when i restart the bot, it starts from 1 again.

Comment: You have multiple choices, you can store tickets in json files, database else you can check the last channel name and parse the ticket number

Comment: I think, just add `if (message.guild.channels.find("t-${client.userTickets.size}")) client.userTickets.size = client.userTickets.size + 1;` right?

Comment: The thing is, I've never worked with databases, I was planning on learning how to use it for the mute and ban stuff.

Comment: `const channels = await message.guild.channels.fetch();
channels.find(channel => channel.name.startsWith('t-'))`
and after get the last item

Comment: What do you mean by `Last Item`